# Sheets Custom Function - Arrays? or Ranges? What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write the most basic of functions and struggling The purpose of the script is to take 2 inputs (ranges) and then use those cells to construct a single, long string of the contents of all the cells concatenated....it doesn't work (see code below).

It has something to do with a range not really being an array because when I hardcoded the array it worked fine. If I have this layout:

```
Header1         Header2
Comment1        Comment2
Comment1a       Comment2a
```

Note that each string is in its own cell in the spreadsheet.  What I want is to get:

```
Header1
    Comment1
    Comment1a

Header2
    Comment2
    Comment2a
```

BUT all of this should be in a single cell.

Instead, what happens is:

```
Header1, Header2
Comment1, Comment1a, Comment2, Comment2a
```

all in a single cell.

Here is my current code....totally confused and no documentation anywhere intelligible doesn't help.

```
function concatComments(headerRange,commentRange)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var out=''
  newline = String.fromCharCode(10)

  hVals = headerRange.split()
  cVals = commentRange.split()
  return hVals

  // Test whether input is an array.
 if (headerRange.map  && commentRange.map)
 {
   /* process array or range */
   // headerRange = ['Header1','Header2']
   // commentRange = ['comment1','comment2', 'comment2a']

   // var hValues = ss.getRange(headerRange).getValues()
   // var cValues = ss.getRange(commentRange).getValues()

   for( i=0; i< commentRange.length; i++)
   {  
    if(commentRange[i].length >= 0) 
    {
      out += headerRange[i] + newline + "    " + commentRange[i] + newline
    }
   }
 }
 else
 {
   /*process single value */ 
   out = headerRange[0] +  newline + "    " + commentRange[0]
 }
  return out
}
```

If anyone could explain what is going on I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

paul

Comment: Make sure to use correct javascript. You are missing all semicolons and have a return upfront so code doesnt execute. Exactly was docs are unclear? Offcial docs explain this well.

Answer (score 0):

**Extracting Arrays from Google Sheets with Google Apps Scripts using the:
getRange().getValues() methods**

```
Header1         Header2    .getValues() for headers
Comment1        Comment2      | .getValues() for comments
Comment1a       Comment2a     |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Use the following test arrays as this is what will be returned by getValues():

```
[["Header1","Header2"]] 
[["Comment1", "Comment2"],["Comment1a", "Comment2a"]]
```

so, being that array indices are zero based:

```
    headers[0][1] == "Header2"
    comments[1][0] == "Comment1a"
    comments[1] == ["Comment1a", "Comment2a"]
```

Empty cells are represented by ""

```
Comment1        Comment2
                Comment2a
```

Would be represented as:

```
[["Comment1", "Comment2"],["", "Comment2a"]]
```

each row is an array within the larger array and every row array will contain the same number of elements even when some cells are empty.

**To find out the number of:**

**Rows** `comments.length`returns the number of row arrays

**Columns** `comments[0].length`returns the number of elements(columns) in the first row array and being that all row arrays contain the same number of elements only one need be used to derive the number of columns.

See if this works:(arguments are returned as value arrays therefore .getValues() is not used)

```
function concatComments(headerRange,commentRange) {
  var out=''
  var newline = String.fromCharCode(10);
  for(var c = 0; c < headerRange[0].length; c++) {
    if( c > 0 ) out = out + newline;
    out = out + headerRange[0][c] + newline;
    for(var r = 0; r < commentRange.length; r++) {
      if(commentRange[r][c] != "") {
        out = out + "     " + commentRange[r][c] + newline;
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Some call it a 2d array. Henrique, more correctly, refers to it as a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without Apps Script with the `JOIN` Sheets function, e.g.

```
=JOIN(" ", A1:A3)
```

Will concatenate the values in A1:A3 separated by a space.

For your example, you'd need something more complicated like

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),A1, ARRAYFORMULA("   " & A2:A3), B1, ARRAYFORMULA("   " & B2:B3))
```

[[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mfIjkUxgYkGxLlq6E46ahBZ8kLmOgihf0ad_qMmr_iw/edit#gid=0)]